# Tailwind text color not changing on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, hover, tailwind-css, textcolor

I'm trying to get the text color in a button to change when I hover over it but it doesn't work...
My React code is this

```html
<button className="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-light hover:bg-light hover:border-2 hover:border-blue-500 hover:text-blue-500">Sign Up</button>
```

and my tailwind config file looks like this

```js
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                light: "#e2f3f5",
                teal: "#22d1ee",
                blue: "#3d5af1",
                dark: "#0e153a",
            },
        },
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {
            fontSize: ["hover", "focus"],
            backgroundOpacity: ["active"],
            borderWidth: ["hover", "focus"],
            textColor: [
                "responsive",
                "dark",
                "group-hover",
                "focus-within",
                "hover",
                "focus",
            ],
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Yet the text color does not change on hover. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're attempting to extend Tailwind's base theme and one of your custom colors is called blue. By doing this you have made `bg-blue-500` not exist. If you want to extend blue you can add shades as explained here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#extending-the-defaults but by doing this you have replaced blue instead of extending it.

Once you remove that everything should work and you don't even need to have all those extended variants for textColor in your config.

Here it is working on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/7CUThekLY1?file=config

However, if what you really wanted was to have a class like `bg-blue` alongside your other `bg-blue-[xxx]` classes then you need to extend blue and add a key for `DEFAULT` like this:

```
...
theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                light: "#e2f3f5",
                teal: "#22d1ee",
                dark: "#0e153a",
                blue: {
                  'DEFAULT': '#f00'
                }
            },
        },
    },
...
```

Here's an example where I made `bg-blue` red for demonstration. https://play.tailwindcss.com/VYDBylQOPu

Comment: I implemented your changes and as long as I have text-light, the text color doesnt change when hovering. When I put the text color to anything other than the custom defined color (ie text-green-500), the text color does change upon hover, but not when I use a custom color such as text-dark, text-teal etc. Even though it works in your example... Any idea why?

Comment: Actually never mind, I had some old CSS code that was causing the problem, once I removed it the problem dissapeared. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted!